# How to select the dropdown option in aspx page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have set of pre defined dropdown menu, i'm getting the dropdown needs to be selected in the viewdata object but dont no how to select the option in .aspx page

Here how my menu looks

```
<td headers="Vehicle" style="background-color:#EFF3FB;font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px;"><select>
  <option value="Car">Car</option>
  <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
  <option value="Lorry">Lorry</option>
  <option value="Truck">Truck</option>
</select>

</td>
```

Here is the `ViewData.Model.VehicleDetails.Vehicle` will have the vehicle needs to be selected. but dont no how to select it inside the aspx page.

Comment: it is populate from datbase, show that action and code where you pouplating it

Comment: Hi, ViewData.Model.VehicleDetails.Vehicle contains the value like Car, Bus,Lorry etc... this value comes from DB and it happens in Linq, from controller i'm passing it to Aspx page

Comment: which option you want to select by default?

Comment: whatever the value present in "ViewData.Model.VehicleDetails.Vehicle" this object i need to select

Comment: show the code where you populating it

Comment: I'm not getting, which code you want?. This is the aspx code. if i need to display text present in viewdata i simply write "<td headers="name"><%= ViewData.Model.ElementAt.EmployeeName%></td>" Like this i need to select the option in dropdown based on value present in viewdata object

Comment: how to creating these select tags you are binding from cs file right, your are using aspx view not razor view right

Comment: Yes i'm not using Razor, select tag is hardcoded. only one value at a time needs to be selected based on value present in ViewData.Model.VehicleDetails.Vehicle variable. Assume i'm hardcoding in c# like VehicleDetails.Vehicle = "Car". in this case how to select car when i launch aspx page

Comment: you can do it with jquery that one then

Comment: Can you please post syntax. actually values comes in loop. since its table. if there are ten elements, then 10 rows comes. and each row has to be selected by corrusponding value

Comment: see the answer post hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add another property in you mode for list:

```
public class YourModel
{
 public SelectList VehiclesList {get;set;}
 public string SelectedVehicle {get;set;}
}
```

In Action:

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="Car",Value="Care"});
list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="Bus",Value="Bus"});
list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="Truck",Value="Truck"});

yourModel.VehiclesList = new SelectList(list,"Value","Text", ViewData.Model.VehicleDetails.Vehicle);
```

In View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedVehicle , Model.VehiclesList)%>
```

**Updated:**

you can also do like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(ViewControlNames.vehicle, 
                   new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                  new SelectListItem{ Text="Car", Value = "car" }, 
                                  new SelectListItem{ Text="Bus", Value = "Bus" }, 
                                  new SelectListItem{ Text="Truck", Value = "Truck" } },"Bus"), 
                                  new { id = ViewControlNames.vehicle, Class = "ShortInputField"})) %>
```

Comment: SelectListItem is not getting recognized in my c# Code :(, no assmebly for that :(

Comment: add this in that class: using System.Web.Mvc;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i'm trying ur solution but. cant we do something like " <%=Html.DropDownList(ViewControlNames.vehicle, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{ Text="Car", Value = "car" }, new SelectListItem{ Text="Bus", Value = "Bus" }, new SelectListItem{ Text="Truck", Value = "Truck" } }, new { id = ViewControlNames.vehicle, Class = "ShortInputField", "Some attribute to select"})%> Here we can put some attribute to select directly without writing code in c#??

Comment: you can do that way but recommended way is what i have told you, you can do this way set the selected attribute on condition

Comment: The above way wont work, i did slight change DropDownList(ViewControlNames.vehicle, 
                   new List<SelectListItem> { 
                                  new SelectListItem{ Text="Car", Value = "car" }, 
                                  new SelectListItem{ Text="Bus", Value = "Bus" }, 
                                  new SelectListItem{ Text="Truck", Value = "Truck" } },"Bus", 
                                  new { id = ViewControlNames.vehicle, Class = "ShortInputField"})) %>. It worked but there is a duplication i.e always selected item repeats in the list.

Comment: i dont know how you want to do it, the up two ways are fine to do but i didnt got what you are trying to maek

Comment: Hi, thanks, what i'm lookling for is from DB "ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).Vehicle" will have the data. i.e value of the dropdown list. There is a predefined list as i shown above i need to select the matching item of "ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).Vehicle" at run time. thats all

Comment: so where i am passing bus in the last update you can pass ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).Vehicle whats the big deal in it

Comment: Some how i did it like below, ans but its not recomended. but is there a way you can make it more generic. tell me. i have posted my ans below. Thank you for your help, Thank you very much3

Comment: this came very first one in my mind but its the worst approach so i don't posted it as its not a quality answer

Comment: Yes true, but can we make it more generic?, in the second approach you have provided the item in list gets duplicated. it should not duplicate right?, though we are not adding it as new item, why it get duplicated. ?

Comment: Hi, Whats wrong with this approach?, 
 <%=Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.managerDetails.ElementAt(i).vehicle, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                         new SelectListItem{ Text="Car", Value = "car" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Bus", Value = "Bus" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Truck", Value = "Truck" }
                        
                     }, new { id = ViewControlNames.vehicle, Class = "ShortInputField", })%>. In this lamda experssion is not giving any values only. whats wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<%if (ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).vehicle == "Car")%>
<%{%>
  <option value="car" selected="selected">car</option>
  <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
  <option value="Lorry">Lorry</option>

<%} %>
<%else if (ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).vehicle == "Bus")%>
<%{%>
   <option value="car" >car</option>
  <option value="Bus" selected="selected">Bus</option>
  <option value="Lorry">Lorry</option>

<%} %>
<%else if (ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).vehicle == "Lorry")%>
<%{%>
 <option value="car">car</option>
  <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
  <option value="Lorry" selected="selected">Lorry</option>

<%} %>

</select>
```